# Pardot has something looks like Social Customer Service

Tags: pardot

I have a question about the Social Listening in Pardot. In Social Studio integrated with Salesforce we can create case or leads from inbox messages or direct messages received from customers in Social Customer Service.

In Pardot - do we have a tool with similar features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need Social Studio, as Pardot itself does not have any integrations allowing you to create Prospect records from inbox messages or posts.